# SSL installation for a frontend/api, any idea how to configure it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, ssl, heroku

I'm digging into the SSL installation for my app and it seems that my "basic" questions for the "how to start an ssl config" didn't find a clear answer.

I use a frontend in node that calls an API running on Ruby on Rails.

My front app delivers a multiple subdomain front service. Both (back and front) are hosted on Heroku and DNS points to 1and1 management.

I found some first steps with Geotrust provided by 1and1 and another choice that goes to letsencrypt.

My questions are :

1. If I had to choose one, which one between the backend and frontend would welcome the certificate ?
2. I tried to install a (paid, ofc.) Geotrust certificate on 1and1 but it fails. Is it related to the CNAME 1and1 <-> Heroku complexity, or because I didn't install the key yet on the app (and I don't know how) ?
3. If I plan to use SSL on front, I found installation of letsencrypt quite confusing. Between the npm letsencrypt and the "getting started" of the official website, there's a gap. Should I really need the node package ? Or is the certbot quite enough for making it working ?

Lots of informations but clearly not really operational for me. I'm sorry, probably I miss a thing in my readings.

Comment: You may be overthinking it. You should install the certificates on the frontend and backend app on heroku - follow [the instructions from Heroku devcenter](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint). SSL is handled on the server layer so neither your Node or Rails application really need to be concerned with it.

Comment: Thx @max for your help. But yes, I followed the heroku page, but still stuck on the SSL provider step : "Next, begin the process of creating a new SSL certificate with your chosen certificate provider. This will vary depending on your provider, but at some point you will need to upload the CSR generated in the previous step." What should I do then on this step ? I need this step in order to obtain the .crt file, no ?

Comment: also I wanted to test the certbot and letsencrypt scripts but was kicked as I'm using shell command on Mac .... :(

Comment: Thanks @max for your help. I couldn't have a clear vision about what to do, as I'm stuck on multiple parts of the SSL. I will probably change my app host because heroku couldn't help me on the part about subdomains and certificates. I need time to think about it.